# ks0108 vs NT7108 lcd controller

Tags: lcd

I need to replace a LCD display that has built in a ks0108 controller.

I have found a replacement that really fit all the specs (dimensions, resolution, maH, Voltage) but has a Neotec NT7108 Built in controller instead.

on the web i found this source:
http://serdisplib.sourceforge.net/ser/ks0108.html

that says that the 2 different controller are compliant.

I'm not 100% sure if I can replace a ks0108 with a  NT7108 and/or if is going to be a problem of any sort.

"Compliant" would lead me to think that i won't have problems but the website is unknown to me and need to be sure.

I never have selected neither worked with displays before, so i need some help here. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a look in the [KS0108 datasheet](http://www.hpinfotech.ro/KS0108.pdf) and the [NT7108 datasheet](https://www.crystalfontz.com/controllers/Neotec/NT7108/153/) and they do indeed seem extremely similar.

They are pin compatible, have the same electrical specifications, timing specifications and the same set of instructions/registers.

They are basically the same chip from two different manufacturers.

Comment: True. KS0108 is the re-named version of the famous S6B0108 from Samsung. NT7108 is one of the KS0108 equivalents, such as HD61202 from Hitachi.

Comment: thanks a lot, you were very helpful. now i can replace the LCD without much anxiety :)

Comment: @nhouse Glad I could help. If you are happy with the answer, please consider marking the answer as accepted so that the question is considered answered.